# SKlearn votingClassifier() cloned model showing NOneType for parameter

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, tf.keras, multiclass-classification

I have a base estimator class I created that trains a NN from TF.keras

something like:

```
TF_NN(BaseEstimator):
    def __init__(self,...,parameter='defaultstring', metric='accuracy', ...):
        self.parameter = parameter
        self.metric=metric
        ... #build a tf.keras n_network + methods + other assignments
```

Now here is the part that is odd. I run this code

```
nn = TF_NN(...,parameter='some_string',...)
clf = VotingClassifier( [('nn', nn), (...), (...)] )
clf.fit(x,y)
```

and when I check the class parameters of clf after the run of clf.fit I get this - here the left hand is the code run, the right side of the equal’s sign is the returned value both after running clf.fit(). In other words these are Not assignment statements in my code. They are simply stored values after running fit() showing that the cloned copies which are the fitted estimators no longer contain a value for the ‘parameter’ value. On the other hand the ‘metric’ parameter works fine.

```
print(clf.estimators[0][1].parameter) #returns 'some_string'
print(clf.estimators_[0][1].parameter) #returns {NoneType} None 
print(clf.estimators[0][1].metric) #returns 'accuracy'
print(clf.estimators_[0][1].metric) #returns 'accuracy'
```

Any reason why that may be happening? It isn't happening for all of my input parameters as you can see. Its like in the clone stage of `clf.fit`, it missed one of my parameters.

And if I instead do inside my TF_NN class **init**:

```
self.parameter = 'some_string'
```

it works fine where both estimators and estimators_ show the correct value.

Essentially the end goal for stage 1 is to have a Voting classifier that can use a tensorflow NN as one of its voting criteria. For what it's worth,

```
parameter == outputActivation #activation used on output Layer. softmax for multiclass classification.
```

Comment: What's the meaning of `clf.estimators[0][1].metric = 'accuracy'` (and why you are repeating it)? Do you *set* it, or you *ask* for it (i.e. you give `clf.estimators[0][1].metric` and you get `'accuracy'` as a result?

Comment: I’ll update to clarify. Once I run fit those lines are checked to see what values are saved. Those are debug lines (the equal sign is there to show the return value. The estimator line is the trained model. Estimator_ is the cloned model in VotingClassifier if skkearn.

Comment: This notation is highly misleading, and it should not be used! Use `print` statements instead...

Comment: You are right. Is that better?